# What equipment do I need to transfer audio from MiniDisc to hard disk?

Tags: home-studio, digital

I need to transfer some recordings made on MiniDisc to my MacBook computer.

My MiniDisc has an S/PDIF digital output, so I imagine I need to buy something that will connect to my computer via USB which provides an S/PDIF input?

I've found plenty of USB audio interfaces, but none which seem to provide a digital optical input. I'd also rather not pay for an expensive box with fancy A/D converters, as I don't need those - I just want to transfer the digital recording on the MiniDisc directly to hard disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which model of macbook you have, but most of them have a digital (optical) input built in on the line input. You would just have to grab a mini-toslink adaptor and change it to optical on system preferences > sound.

You could try it by searching apple database or trying to enable this option on your settings?
If I remember correctly I could see the beam straight away (sold my macbook a year ago i think).

Comment: The [Apple.se](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) site might be able to help with this.

Comment: ahah! there's an apple one! brilliant! thanks neilfein!

Comment: Thanks - according to http://support.apple.com/kb/SP500 I do have a digital input, so this should be simpler than I thought!